# How to Get RAW content, NOT HTML of response after page loaded using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

**NOTE** `driver.page_source` or `driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")` always returns a string.

I'm looking for a way to get the raw content of the request using selenium, not just the parsed html by using `driver.page_source`, but reading the fully raw content of network response like `requests`:

```
sess = requests.Session()
res_content = sess.get('https://my_url/video1.mp4').content

with open('file.any', mode='wb') as file:
     file.write(res_content)
```

**Here you can get the raw content, being html(string) or any other format...**

---

**I'm trying to do the same using selenium, I searched all over the internet and didn't find a solution.**

My current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class EdgeSession(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.driver = webdriver.Edge(Service=)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15)

        
    def get(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
    
        content_type = self.driver.execute_script("return document.contentType")
        content_type = content_type.lower() if content_type is str else content_type
            
        if 'text' in content_type.lower():
            self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))
            self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'style')))

            return self.driver.page_source, content_type
        else:
            return ??? response.content??, content_type


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sess = EdgeSession()
    
    content, content_type = sess.get('https://www.etsu.edu/uschool/faculty/braggj/documents/frenchrevolution.pdf')
    
    #OR
     
    content, content_type = sess.get('https://youtubdle.com/watch?v=gwUN5UuRhdw&format=.mp4') #...
    
    if content_type == "application/pdf" or 'video/mp4':
        with open(f'my_raw_file.{content_type.split('/')[1]}', mode='wb') as file:
            file.write(content)
```

Here if I use `content = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")` it just returns a parsed HTML.

Comment: PDF is binary data, you shouldn't encode it as text. The same with images.